# Weblogic ProxyServlet in web.xml dynamic IP adress in

Tags: redirect, proxy, weblogic

I use ProxyServlet in web.xml in order to redirect requests from the frontend serveur to the backend server.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ProxyServlet</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>weblogic.servlet.proxy.HttpProxyServlet</servlet-class> 
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>WebLogicHost</param-name> 
        <param-value>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</param-value> 
    </init-param> 

    <init-param> 
        <param-name>WebLogicPort</param-name> 
        <param-value>xxxx</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
</servlet>
```

But my problem is that I want to use a dynamic IP adress and port... so can I use env value or somthing else. Because I want to deploy the same WAR into diffrent servers.

weblogic 12c

Comment: You can use a deployment plan to update param values in your different environments.
Please note that the Proxy Servlet should be used only for dev purpose. In production you should use a "real" http server such as Apache or HAProxy for better performances.

Comment: You can use domain name/hothname (DNS), instead of IP address.

Comment: zappee: how can I do this in web.xml file

Comment: Thank you  Emmanuel Collin for the reply. Is there an example of a deployment plan in the case of WebLogic ProxyServlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Emmanuel Collin.
The solution is to use a deployment plan which is an xml file that we put on each server (DEV, QUALIF, PROD) and in each file we put the value of IP address and port.